# does tapply by default excludes the NA on the variable passed for segmentation?

Tags: r, tapply

I have a data frame (`a`) where two columns are `total_amount` and `Gender`. I need to calculate total amount spent by Males and females.

In Gender column, there are `NA`s as well. On running the following command

```
tapply(a$total_amount,a$Gender, sum)
```

The result is:

```
 F        M 
23623513 24935632
```

My query is: does `tapply` by default remove missing values in the segment column selected for categorisation i.e. Gender in this case? if yes, then how can we include them in our results?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  We don't know the structure of your data.  Normally, if there is NA, and if you haven't provided `na.rm=TRUE` in the `sum`, then that value would be `NA` `tapply(c(NA, 3, 4, 2), rep(1:2, 2), FUN = sum) #1  2 
NA  5`

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the `help(tapply`),

> tapply(X, INDEX, FUN = NULL, ..., default = NA, simplify = TRUE)
>
> INDEX: a ‘list’ of one or more ‘factor’s, each of same length as
>             ‘X’.  The elements are coerced to factors by ‘as.factor’.

By checking the `tapply` code

```
INDEX <- lapply(INDEX, as.factor)
...
namelist <- lapply(INDEX, levels)
```

---

It means, the grouping variable is converted to `factor`.  The `levels` of the `factor` exclude `NA` elements and that would be the reason in the output we don't have any `NA` as group

```
tapply(c(3, 4, 2, 6), c(NA, 1, 3, 4), sum) 
#  1 3 4 
#  4 2 6
```

However, if the `NA` elements are converted to strings, it will be a `level` when converted to `factor`

```
tapply(c(3, 4, 2, 6), c("NA", 1, 3, 4), sum)
# 1  3  4 NA 
# 4  2  6  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.

You can do a `sum(is.na(a$Gender))`. This will give you the number of rows which have `NA`'s.
And if you want to look at the sum of the respective `NA`'s then,

```
x <- a[is.na(a$Gender), ]

sum(x$gender_total)
```